# ¿como puedo descargar una imagen almacenada en mi base de datos mysql BLOB en formato jpg?

Tags: php, mysql, blob

Si logro ver la imagen almacenada en la base de datos, mi problema es que ya tengo 2GB mi base datos y se esta descontrolando , quiero manejarlo ahora las imagenes como archivos independientes y en la base de datos guardar solo la URL y no todo el archivo completo.
cuadno quiero ver la imagen uso este codigo, pero para descargarlo Click Derecho guardar iamgen imagen, lo hace en formato php, me podrian ayudar porfavor?

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['abono_id'])){
    include ("conexion.php");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM abonos WHERE abono_id = {$_GET['abono_id']}");
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $imgData = $result->fetch_assoc();        
        header("Content-type: image/jpg"); 
        echo $imgData['voucher'];
    }else{
        echo '#';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola. Depura tu código y dinos qué tienes exactamente en `$imgData`. Puedes usar por ejemplo `var_dump($imgData);` y comentar temporalmente la línea del `header`.